# How to prevent Rust's std::process:Command from inserting .exe's relative path into arguments?

Tags: windows, cmd, rust

I'm using Rust's `std:process:Command` to call `robocopy` in Windows. Unfortunately, it seems that somewhere along the execution of `robocopy`, the relative path from the .exe is inserted before each directory.

Additionally, simple calls like `net use` work with the same method, though I've only tested ones that don't rely on any directories.

Edit: updated the test folders to have spaces in their names.

**Edit 2: the code has been updated with the solution. The solution was to call robocopy directly and `.arg()` in everything individually. Old attempts are still commented in.**

Instead of sending

```
cmd.exe /c robocopy "C:\Test\Test 1" "C:\Test\Test 2" /MIR /copy:DAT /MT:32 /Z /R:2 /W:03 /v /LOG:"C:\Test\Test 3\logfile.log"
```

and it running successfully, the output has a lot of errors:

```
ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Opening Log File C:\relative\path\where\exe\is\located\"C:\Test\Test 3\logfile.log"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Started : Tuesday, January 8, 2019 7:35:41 AM
    Source - C:\relative\path\where\exe\is\located\"C:\Test\Test 1"\
      Dest - C:\relative\path\where\exe\is\located\"C:\Test\Test 2"\

     Files :
   Options : /V /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /Z /MT:32 /R:2 /W:3

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #10 : "/LOG:"C:\Test\Test 3\logfile.log""
```

This issue occurs using:

- Rust version 1.3.1
- Windows 10

Code that causes this for me is shown below. To use it you'll need to put a **Test** folder in your **C:\** (or change it to wherever) and put inside that directory a **Test 1** folder with some **Testfile.txt** to help show copying took place, as well as a **Test 3** folder for the log to be in (not sure if the log can make its own folder - so just to be safe, premake one for it!). Basically you want:

```
C:\Test\Test 1\Testfile.txt (name or type of file doesn't matter)
C:\Test\Test 3\
```

`robocopy` should run and make a **C:\Test\Test 2** folder with **Testfile.txt** in it and put a **logfile.log** in **C:\Test\Test 3** that details the transaction. In the end, the directories should look like this:

```
C:\Test\Test 1\Testfile.txt
C:\Test\Test 2\Testfile.txt
C:\Test\Test 3\logfile.log
```

The code follows:

```
//-----Import Built-in Libraries (not called crates)-----
use std::process::Command; //use cmd.exe

fn main()
{
    let commandOpt1 = "/MIR"; //mirror directories
    let commandOpt2 = "/copy:DAT"; //copy attributes
    let commandOpt3 = "/MT:32"; //use 32 I/O threads (low CPU still, but better bandwidth utilization)
    let commandOpt4 = "/Z"; //idr
    let commandOpt5 = "/R:2"; //Retry twice
    let commandOpt6 = "/W:03"; //Wait 3 sec between tries
    let commandOpt7 = "/v"; //verbose logging
    let commandLogStr = "/LOG:\"C:\\Test\\Test 3\\logfile.log\""; //record where the log file goes
    let commandLogNoParenthStr = "/LOG:C:\\Test\\Test 3\\logfile.log"; //record where the log file goes
    let command = format!("robocopy \"C:\\Test\\Test 1\" \"C:\\Test\\Test 2\" {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}",
    commandOpt1,commandOpt2,commandOpt3,commandOpt4,commandOpt5,commandOpt6,
    commandOpt7,commandLogStr); //build the command
    let commandStr: &str = &*command; //these two types of strings are
    println!("TEST-Command for robocopy:{}",command);

    //let m = Command::new("cmd.exe").arg("/c").arg(commandStr).output().unwrap(); //run cmd.exe net use
    /*let m = Command::new("cmd.exe")
        .arg("/c")
        .arg("robocopy")
        .arg("\"C:\\Test\\Test 1\"")
        .arg("\"C:\\Test\\Test 2\"")
        .arg(commandOpt1)
        .arg(commandOpt2)
        .arg(commandOpt3)
        .arg(commandOpt4)
        .arg(commandOpt5)
        .arg(commandOpt6)
        .arg(commandOpt7)
        .arg(commandLogStr)
        .output().unwrap(); //run cmd.exe net use */
    let m = Command::new("robocopy")
        .arg("C:\\Test\\Test 1")
        .arg("C:\\Test\\Test 2")
        .arg(commandOpt1)
        .arg(commandOpt2)
        .arg(commandOpt3)
        .arg(commandOpt4)
        .arg(commandOpt5)
        .arg(commandOpt6)
        .arg(commandOpt7)
        .arg(commandLogNoParenthStr )
        .output().unwrap(); //run cmd.exe net use */
    let mOutput = String::from_utf8_lossy(&m.stdout); //get the output
    println!("TEST-cmd output: {}",mOutput);
    println!("TEST-cmd status: {}", m.status.success()); //reports success (true or false) of command
    println!("TEST-cmd stderr: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&m.stderr)); //reports error words of command
    let _ = Command::new("cmd.exe").arg("/c").arg("pause").status(); // wait for user input
}
```

The code gives two options, one to call `robocopy` in one `.arg()` addition and one with the `.arg()`s split up. For me, they give the same result - but options are good!

Also, as a note, I send everything into `Command` as a `&str` but that seems to not be required - `Strings` can be `.arg()`s too.

Comment: Do **not** edit your *question* to contain an *answer*. You are encouraged to post your own answer below instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a Windows machine nearby but I'm quite sure that the problem is in the quote characters `"`.

Escape rules in CMD.exe are quite weird: sometimes you need quotes, sometimes you do not, and sometime you must not use them.

In your case, the log file, for example is chosen with the following option (removing Rust escapes): `/LOG:"C:\Test\Test3\logfile.log"`. This is a file name that starts and ends with a quote. And since it does not start with a drive letter or a `\`, the OS thinks: surely it is a relative path, let's look for `C:\...\"C:\Test..."`!

The solution is easy: just remove all those quote.

What I don't understand is why are you calling `cmd.exe /c` instead of just calling `robocopy` directly.  Quotes in the command line are used to guide the command line parser and properly manage filenames with spaces and so on. But if you do `Command::new()` of `robocopy` directly, then there is no need for quoting because the arguments are already passed separatedly.

Comment: Removing the `"`'s did fix its execution - but it removed the ability for it to work on directories with spaces in them. If C:\Test\Test1 becomes C:\Test\Test 1 then it fails to read the whole directory. And pasting the whole thing into a command prompt works with `"`'s and all.

As for why I don't call it directly, it errors with `thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the file specified." }', libcore\result.rs:1009:5` if I use `let m = Command::new(commandStr).output().unwrap();` - so I don't.

Comment: Additionally, I just understood you were implying calling `Command::new("robocopy").arg().arg().arg()...` and trying *that* without `"`'s did work!


I just can't call it all in one line, or with cmd.exe starting it! Thanks!

Comment: @user2403531: Glad it worked! The thing with pasting that command line is that `cmd` (the one that reads your command, not the one you are launching) sometimes removes the quotes and split the line into an array of arguments. So the invoked `cmd` does not actually see the quotes. When you call it as in the OP, it does see the quotes and the program breaks.